# extracting a word between brackets using regex pattern

Tags: regex

Am using this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial) to create regular expression for one of my task with input string as:

```
[Begin] { (GetLatestCode)
```

Trying to extract string between brackets i.e. trying to extract **GetLatestCode** for which I made the following:

```
(?<=\[Begin\]\s{\s\()\w+(?=\))     //returns GetLatestCode
```

But this solution does not seem to work when I have multiple spaces around the curly brace.

```
[Begin]    {            (GetLatestCode)     //does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to account for **0 or more spaces**, add a `*` after each space:

`(?<=\[Begin\]\s*{\s*\()\w+(?=\))`

If you need to account for **1 or more**, use a `+`:

`(?<=\[Begin\]\s+{\s+\()\w+(?=\))`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I tried including * after the first \s but failed to do it after the second \s. 
truly appreciate your help.